# Emojis not displaying in Android app (Android studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, emoji

I've Android app which is connected to our Wordpress Website, but now after release we see a problem that when users leave comment in app or is site, everything is ok but emojis display with "?" in the app!

what's wrong here? these emojis are shown correctly in wordpress panel and website.

Comment: You are adding data from website or from app ?

Comment: @MAC comments can both submit in site or in app , but now most of theme submit in app because site doesn't have much user, but app is full of users and submitting cm also with emoji